# Even after I give the condition truth, the answer here always looks false

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Even after I give the conditioned truth, the answer here always looks false.

```js
var AlloverName = ['Iqbal', 'Saidul', 'Ali Akbar']

var isOkay = false

function detailsAllOfYou(activity) {
  for (i = 0; i <= activity.length; i++) {

    if (activity[i] === 'Saidul') {
      console.log("Name is found")
      isOkay = true;
      break
    }
    if (!isOkay) {
      console.log("Name is not found")
      break
    }
  }
}

detailsAllOfYou(AlloverName)
```

Comment: You're breaking on the first not found; if you put the name in question as the *first* element you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: Why do you think you give the condition truth? It never logs "Name is found".

Comment: Unrelated problem: `<=` should be `<`.

Comment: also initialize i in the for loop with let

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your logic, because the array sees the first element isnt equal then breaks, so change it to

```js
var AlloverName = ['Iqbal', 'Saidul', 'Ali Akbar']
var isOkay = false

function detailsAllOfYou(activity) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= activity.length; i++) {

    if (activity[i] === 'Saidul') {
      console.log("Name is found")
      isOkay = true;
      break
    }

  }

  if (!isOkay) {
    console.log("Name is not found")
  }
}

detailsAllOfYou(AlloverName)
```